# What 90s or early 2000s tv show has a leopard-like woman and a super strong man?

Tags: story-identification, tv, medieval

I remember about 8 years ago there was a fantasy TV show going on my local channels with subtitles in my native language of Sinhala, in Sri Lanka.

It was probably from the 90s or early 2000s. I can't remember much about it. I recall there were at least 4 main characters who traveled together in some oppressed world. There was one man who was young and a woman whose face had the features of a leopard. Then an older but very strong man who looked like he was Chinese and had a Chinese sort of beard. I think he had the ability to lift heavy things. I remember him heaving a boulder once. The rest were all Caucasians. There was also a young girl in the group, a kid.

In one of the episodes this girl befriends another child who is also a girl and in the end of the episode it turns out that the other girl turns into a pink hued man-eating monster who has been eating local villagers. I believe there was a fifth character who was a spirit. She would often contact the main character (the young man) and offer advice. In another episode I remember the man (younger one) becomes unconscious and the leopard-like woman tends to him in a mountain cave and when he wakes up his clothes are gone. That is about everything I remember about this. Please help me! It must be a very old TV show, at least 20 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The show is *[The Legend of William Tell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_William_Tell)*. I remembered it after so long. Thankfully, it is on YouTube. Now I face the dilemma of revisiting childhood nostalgia. Thank you all for your assistance.

> Described by executive producer Raymond Thompson as "Star Wars on the planet Earth", this is a fantasy saga of bravery, magic, myth and romance. William Tell is the youthful leader of a band of young, ‘brat pack' outlaws, forever hunted by the forces of darkness, led by Xax and Kreel, who have usurped power in their homeland. The series of self-contained stories follows Will's quest to restore young Princess Vara to her rightful place on the royal throne and defeat Xax and Kreel's forces — and by doing so, bring back peace and order to the Kingdom of Kale.

### Trailer

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the Japanese series [*Monkey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_(TV_series))

This became cult viewing in the west in the early 1980s.

The overall story is that of the bringing of the Buddhist Tripitaka from India to Korea.  However, individual episodes had a variety of monster encounters like those that you mention.

Comment: That isn't the one. Thank you. I can now alter my question. I remember that only that one guy looked Chinese and the rest of them were Caucasian. But the Chinese guy could lift huge boulders. Also I now think that it was most probably produced after the 90s and maybe even the early 2000s? Sorry

Comment: Ah yes.  Now you've edited the question Monkey isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like [*Thunder Cats*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088631/).  Their
 leader, even though he was one of the youngest, was "Lion-o", apparently just because he was a Lion and Lions are the "King of beasts".  There was "Panthera", "Cheetara", etc.

Comment: No it was not a cartoon. I found the answer to my own question. It is The Legend of William Tell. Thank you for your assistance!